# Task scheduler batch job execution

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have a small problem with below batch job execution as shown in the code snippet. The batch job executes just fine when triggered in the directory where it resides (C:\Temp\TestFile). However, I noticed that nothing happens when I schedule the job to execute through task scheduler. The task scheduler uses a service account with 'run whether user is logged in or not' option.

```
    @echo off

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set DateTime=%%a

    set Yr=%DateTime:~0,4%
    set Mon=%DateTime:~4,2%
    set Day=%DateTime:~6,2%
    set Hr=%DateTime:~8,2%
    set Min=%DateTime:~10,2%

    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b *.xlsx ^| findstr /vlg:"valid_naming_conventions.txt"') do move "%%I" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\%%~nI__%Yr%-%Mon%-%Day%%%~xI"
```

I believe the service account is not recognizing the directory. However, after I made the change to below, nothing still happens and files that do not meet valid naming conventions as specified in the text file still remain in the same directory and are not moved to the archive folder:

```
    @echo off

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') do set DateTime=%%a

    set Yr=%DateTime:~0,4%
    set Mon=%DateTime:~4,2%
    set Day=%DateTime:~6,2%
    set Hr=%DateTime:~8,2%
    set Min=%DateTime:~10,2%

    set MY_PATH="C:\Temp\TestFile"

    for /f "delims=" %%I in ('%MY_PATH% /b *.xlsx ^| findstr /vlg:"valid_naming_conventions.txt"') do move "%%I" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\%%~nI__%Yr%-%Mon%-%Day%%%~xI"
```

Your help on this will be greatly appreciated. Looking forward to your suggestions!

---

Output after running task scheduler:

```
    C:\Windows\system32>rem @echo off 

    C:\Windows\system32>for /F "delims=" %a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime | find "."') do set DateTime=%a 

    C:\Windows\system32>set DateTime=20190414170803.358000+120  


    C:\Windows\system32>set Yr=2019 

    C:\Windows\system32>set Mon=04 

    C:\Windows\system32>set Day=14 

    C:\Windows\system32>set Hr=17 

    C:\Windows\system32>set Min=08 

    C:\Windows\system32>set 
    MY_PATH="C:\Temp\TestFile" 

    C:\Windows\system32>for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir /B/A-D "C:\Temp\TestFile"\*.xlsx | findstr /vlg:"valid_naming_conventions.txt"') do move "%I" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\%~nI__2019-04-14%~xI" 

    C:\Windows\system32>move "01-TestFile.xlsx" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\01-TestFile__2019-04-14.xlsx" 

    C:\Windows\system32>move "02-TestFile.xlsx" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\02-TestFile__2019-04-14.xlsx" 

    C:\Windows\system32>move "03-TestFile.xlsx" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\03-TestFile__2019-04-14.xlsx"

    C:\Windows\system32>move "04-TestFile.xlsx" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\04-TestFile__2019-04-14.xlsx" 

    C:\Windows\system32>move "05-TestFile.xlsx" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\05-TestFile__2019-04-14.xlsx" 

    C:\Windows\system32>move "06-TestFile.xlsx" "C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive\06-TestFile__2019-04-14.xlsx"
```

Comment: Does the service account have sufficient permissions to access `C:\Temp\TestFile` and `C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive`?

Comment: @Compo: Yes, both my admin account and the service account have full permissions and have full access over local C: on the server.

Comment: Does the directory, `C:\Temp\TestFile\Archive` exist? And more importantly, why have you used `%MY_PATH%  /b *.xlsx` instead of `Dir /B/A-D %MY_PATH%\*.xlsx`

Comment: @Compo: The directory exists. I tried with your suggested change and still no luck...When I check task scheduler, says (0x1) for last run result instead of the operation completed successfully (0x0).

Comment: @Compo: See output after running task scheduler above. Filenames in the directory seem to be recognized but not moved for some reason.

Comment: If you take a look at your `FindStr` command, it is taking the search strings from a file, that file appears to have been given using only its name. When you run the script as the service account, its current directory is not the same as when you run the file directly in your `cmd.exe` window. That means you need either the full path to the text file or preferably set the working directory at the beginning of the script. I've put up an example answer to show you exactly that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to aid you:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "My_Path=C:\Temp\TestFile"
If Not Exist "%My_Path%\*.xlsx" Exit /B
CD /D "%My_Path%"

Set "ds="
For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy /NJH /L "\|" Null'
)Do If Not Defined ds Set "ds=%%A-%%B-%%C"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    'Dir /B/A-D-L *.xlsx^|FindStr /VLG:"valid_naming_conventions.txt"'
)Do (If Not Exist "Archive\" MD "Archive"
    Move /Y "%%A" "Archive\%%~nA__%ds%%%~xA")
```

*You may wish to consider whether you're intention is for the task to be run in the same directory as the batch file itself. In that case you would not have a hard coded path, because you could expand the special metavariable for the batch file itself, `%0`*:

```bat
@Echo Off
If Exist "%~dp0*.xlsx" (CD /D "%~dp0")Else Exit /B

Set "ds="
For /F "Tokens=1-3Delims=/ " %%A In ('RoboCopy /NJH /L "\|" Null'
)Do If Not Defined ds Set "ds=%%A-%%B-%%C"

For /F "Delims=" %%A In (
    'Dir /B/A-D-L *.xlsx^|FindStr /VLG:"valid_naming_conventions.txt"'
)Do (If Not Exist "Archive\" MD "Archive"
    Move /Y "%%A" "Archive\%%~nA__%ds%%%~xA")
```

Comment: Thanks @Compo, that fixed the issue! :)

Comment: the filenames are appended with datestamp ("ds=%%A-%%B-%%C") when archived, so 01-TestFile.xlsx would become 01-TestFile__2019-04-15. How would it be possible to in addition to this check against system date and delete files older than 2 days - i.e. 2019-04-13 and earlier?